# Using bootstrap dropdown with Om

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, clojurescript, om

This is what I have:

```
(defn view [cursor owner]
  (reify
    om/IDidMount
    (did-mount [_]
      (-> (js/$ ".dropdown-toggle")
          (.dropdown)))

    om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/div #js {:className "dropdown"}
               (dom/button #js {:className "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                                :type "button"
                                :id "dropdownMenu1"} "Dropdown" (dom/span #js {:className "caret"}))
               (dom/ul #js {:className "dropdown-menu"
                            :role "menu"
                            :ariaLabelledby "dropdownMenu1"}
                       (dom/li #js {:role "presentation"}
                               (dom/a #js {:role "menuitem"
                                           :tabIndex "-1"
                                           :href "#"} "Action"))
                       (dom/li #js {:role "presentation"}
                               (dom/a #js {:role "menuitem"
                                           :tabIndex "-1"
                                           :href "#"} "Another action")))))))
```

The problem is that once the dropdown is opened, it does not hide anymore as it should be when one clicks on it or somewhere else. Also keystrokes don't work. I believe a missing something important here, what could it be? I'm using bootstrap 3.1.1 and jquery 1.11.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I do to create a dropdown component:

```
(defn dropdown [cursor owner {:keys [id text values]}]
 (om/component
   (html
     [:div.dropdown
       [:button {:type "button"
                 :class "btn dropdown-toggle"
                 :data-toggle "dropdown"
                 :id id}
                text
                [:span {:class "caret"}]]
       [:ul {:class "dropdown-menu" :role "menu" :aria-labelledby id}
         [:li {:role "presentation"}
           (for [v values] 
             [:a {:role "menuitem" :tabIndex "-1" :href "#"} v])]]])))
```

It hides when it should. I use jQuery 1.11.1, Bootstrap 3.2.0 and [sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono) for clarity but that doesn't affect anything. I don't think you should be using IDidMount for jQuery as all interaction is handled via bootstrap's dropdown JavaScript plugin (which is included in Bootstrap library).

Comment: Thanks Anna! You're right, I don't need IDidMount. But also I was doing it wrong the whole time. Following ReactJs's convention I was trying with :dataToggle instead of :data-toggle. Thats why I was relying on javascript instead of data attributes (hence IDidMount)...

Comment: Everything is kebab case in Om world :-)

Comment: @AnnaPawlicka Not quite "everything" is kebab-case: :className and :onClick (though I use om-tools, which lets me write :class and :on-click :-P)

Comment: She's using sablono, which normalizes names as well: https://github.com/r0man/sablono#html-attributes

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the [Om-Bootstrap](https://github.com/racehub/om-bootstrap) library that I wrote; there's a dropdown component that handles all of this state internally for you.

The dropdown becomes:

```
(:require [om-bootstrap.button :as b])

(b/toolbar
 {}
 (for [title ["Default" "Primary" "Success" "Info" "Warning" "Danger" "Link"]
       :let [style (.toLowerCase title)]]
   (b/dropdown {:bs-style style, :title title}
               (b/menu-item {:key 1} "Action")
               (b/menu-item {:key 2} "Another action")
               (b/menu-item {:key 3} "Something else here")
               (b/menu-item {:divider? true})
               (b/menu-item {:key 4} "Separated link"))))
```

The documentation site at http://om-bootstrap.herokuapp.com has examples and code snippets of how to use all of these components.